# How to have minutes between two times?

Tags: java, time, duration, localtime, minute

I have two times and I want to get the difference in minutes.

Ex:

I have this:

```
09:11:30;09:15:22;
```

And I want to achieve this:

```
3 min passed
```

Note that the 9:15:22 is not 9:15:30 so 4 minutes are not passed already.

Comment: What you have tried till now ? You can convert both input time to seconds , get the difference and then divide by 60 to get difference in minutes. As you are interested only in minutes, you can define 'diffInMin' variable as 'int'

Comment: Two times or two durations? Your title conflicts with the body of your Question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As with any date/time question, get your data into the best representable container, in this case, that would be `LocalTime`

```
DateTimeFormatter pattern = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalTime from = LocalTime.parse("09:11:30", pattern);
LocalTime to = LocalTime.parse("09:15:22", pattern);
```

From there you can simply use the API to do the work for you, in this case, making use of `Duration`...

```
Duration duration = Duration.between(from, to);
System.out.println(duration.toMinutes());
```

Which prints `3` (pretty sure you can add the rest of the formatting)

For more information, you could have a look at [the Date/Time tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/index.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
String time1 = "09:11:30";
String time2 = "09:15:22";

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
Date date1 = format.parse(time1);
Date date2 = format.parse(time2);
long difference = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime(); 
long difInMinute = (difference/1000)/60;
System.out.println(difInMinute+" min passed");
```

Credits: Uros K

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: OK Thanks, I'll keep in mind